Rendering geodesics on a hexagon-generated torus
Inspired by this question and a failed attempt on my part to answer it.
Consider a hexagon with each side congruent with and parallel to its opposite. Then the diagonals between the antipodal pairs of vertices are concurrent and divide the hexagon into six congruent triangular parts when they are drawn into it.
We now form a tube by bringing one pair of opposing edges together, give one end of the tube a half-twist, then bring the ends together so that the convex and concave portions merge and create a torus.
To complete forming the torus, you need to stretch the outer parts of the end-joined tube and squeeze the inner parts, and then it is uncertain that the divided hexagon reyains the properties needed to answer the referenced question.

Under what conditions of stretching and squeezing do the edges and antipodal diagonals originally drawn on the planar hexagon remain geodesic on the tours? Would using a torus with circular cross-secions and axial symmetry work?

How can the original angles be preserved so that we guarantee the angular congruence and 180° angle sum for all six triangles?


